# If $(f\circ g)(x)$ is continuous and $f(x)$ is continuous, so is $g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $(f\circ g)(x)$ is continuous and $f(x)$ is continuous, so is $g(x)$?
If $(f\circ g)(x)$ is continuous and $g(x)$ is continuous, so is $f(x)$?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is two times negative. For the first one, take $f(x) = 0$ everywhere and $g(x)$ any discontinuous function. For the second one, take $g(x)=0$ everywhere and $f(x)$ any discontinuous function.